# DQL/SQL to Excel - obtain results of multiple SELECT statements in spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, sql-server, sql, export

I wrote T-SQL query that contains few separate SELECT statements.
Each SELECT statement returns different number of columns and represents different properties/features, so that I don't want to join all of them into one SELECT/into one result.

To visualize my query, let me provide simplified example:

```
DECLARE @myNumber bigint;     
SET @myNumber = 5426;

SELECT 'This' as col1, 'is' as col2, 'my' as col3, 'number:' as col4, @myNumber as col5

SELECT 'and' as column1, 'the half' as column2, @myNumber/2 as column3

SELECT * FROM
       (SELECT 'some' as column1, 'union' as column2
             UNION ALL
       SELECT 'second' as column1, 'case' as column2
       ) as someData
```

That's how it looks in SQL Server Management Studio after query execution:

[image: Result of example query execution]

Now, I would like to obtain exactly the same query results in Excel. I go to Data --> From Other Sources --> From SQL Server.
In the 'Import Data' window, I click on Properties and insert the mentioned query:

[image: setting - SQL Server connection]

Unfortunately, only first SELECT query result is displayed in Excel.

[image: only the first query result is obtained in Excel]

Is it possible to retrieve all query results in Excel?

Comment: I don't think you could do it in one connection, use three different connections on three different sheets.

Comment: Well, but I would prefer to define the parameter in one place - will it be possible with three separate connections?

Comment: Currently Excel does NOT support multiple SQL statements in one connection. Full stop. (you may write macro to run queries and emulate your desired behaviour, however that significantly increases complexity).

Comment: Is it possible to do that in LibreOffice? Are there any plans do add such function in next Excel releases? Maybe you could add your comment as a response, so that I could mark it as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel does not support multiple SQL statements in one connection.

As a workaround you may use a macro emulating desired functionality.

Other questions raised in comments:

- Does Microsoft plan to add this functionality in future versions of Excel: I'm not an employee of MS, neither I know their plans.
  However it doesn't seem to be a functionality required by many of the users, I don't expect development to focus on it.
- Do other similar tools (e.g. open office) support multiple SQL statements? I don't know those tools.

Answer (score -1):

**You can use multiple UNION for this, below are few sample SQL Query Code Lines, will help you to fix the problem.**

```
SELECT Distinct value
From ((Select field1 as value from table1 where data = value) union all
      (Select field2 from table1 where data = value) union all
      (Select field1 from table2 where data = value) union all
      (Select field2 from table2 where data = value)
     ) t
```

or it should like this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Field
FROM (
    SELECT  b.Field
    FROM    Table1 tab
    CROSS APPLY ( 
        SELECT c.Field1 AS Field
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT c.Field2 AS Field
    ) AS X
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  b.Field
    FROM    Table2 tab
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT c.Field1 AS Field
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT c.Field2 AS Field
    ) AS x
) y
```

*First one is simple and easy to use,, Hope this help you.*

Comment: `UNION` requires different results to have the same number of columns and data types, this is not the case in the question.

Comment: @MátéJuhász,, both are working in SQL SERVER 2007 and this was the only possibility could connect all 3,, then move to EXCEL, since Excel import Database doesn't supports what OP tried.

Comment: Although your query works, it doesn't solve the problem. Neither it explains at which extent is a solution and what compromises are necessary.

Comment: Valuable add on by eXperts could improve the Solution,,, help the OP ,,, please suggest some SQL Code lines.